# Regex strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Input strings:

```
str1 = "$13.90 Price as Shown"
str2 = "$590.50  $490.00 Price as Selected" 
str3 = "$9.90 or 5/$27.50 Price as Selected"
```

Output strings:

```
str1 = "13.90"
str2 = "490.00"
str3 = "9.90"
```

My code to get output:

```
str = str.strip.gsub(/\s\w{2}\s\d\/\W\d+.\d+/, "") # remove or 5/$27.50 from string
str = /\W\d+.\d+\s\w+/.match(str).to_s.gsub("$", "").gsub(" Price", "")
```

This code works fine for all 3 different types of strings. But how can I improve my code? Are there any better solutions?
Also guys can you give link to good regex guide/book?

Comment: A good regex intro [here](http://regexone.com/)

Comment: **Output strings:** is what is want or what you already have ?

Comment: What I want, and what I already can do with this code

Comment: The problem seems to be `string2`, the rest is easy.

Comment: My code works fine for all 3 types of strings. Just wondering how can I improve that code :)

Comment: Please formulate the requirements. And please try [`(?<!\/)\$\d+.\d+(?=\s\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/pL3sL7/1).

Comment: I'm a bit confused.. For the "Price as Selected" strings, how are you determining which of the 2 prices are being selected? Also, are you parsing these strings from somewhere? If this is information being passed from a form, or something similar, then you can pass one of the 2 prices based on the selection, and then only have to worry about parsing the string with the single price displayed

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting this strings from other resources. I need to get second (lower) (sale) price when 2 prices is provided in string

Comment: stribizhev, nice, thank you!

Comment: Why not just parse out all numbers and select the lowest programmatically?

Comment: With regex in Ruby, you cannot compare matched numbers. That regex will not work as per your requirements. You should do what @dustmouse says.

Comment: dustmouse - I can't parse just numbers, they are in html.text with "Price as selected" stuff.

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/ax6T99). I extract the floats as strings, parse them as float numbers, and get the minimum value. Isn't it what you are looking for?

Comment: Wow, nice solution. But in my situation, I don't really need to compare. Because when 2 prices in string - I always need second (lower **it is always lower, it is *sale price*), but when string is 9.90 or 5/27.50 I should select first price, because it is for single item.

Comment: Ok, is [this code](http://ideone.com/k73weB) working as expected?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!!!

Comment: @rubylifequestions I know you've already accepted an answer and that's cool, but I've updated my answer with a shorter regex.

Comment: Several people have asked you to state your question, but you have refused to do so. That warrants a downvote. I will retract it if you edit your question to state what you want to do in in words. (Do not try to explain in a comment, as not everyone reads all comments.) To give you an example of the ambiguity,what is the significance of `5/` in `str3`? Initially, I thought you were comparing `$9.90` with `$27.50/5 = $5.50`, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex I suggested first is just a sum total of your regexps:

```
(?<=(?<!\/)\$)\d+.\d+(?=\s\w+)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pL3sL7/2)

Since it is next to impossible to compare numbers with regex, I suggest

1. Extracting all float numbers
2. Parse them as float values
3. Get the minimum one

Here is a [working snippet](http://ideone.com/k73weB):

```
def getLowestNumberFromString(input)
    arr = input.scan(/(?<=(?<!\/)\$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?/)
    arr.collect do |value| 
        value.to_f 
    end
    return arr.min
end

puts getLowestNumberFromString("$13.90 Price as Shown")
puts getLowestNumberFromString("$590.50  $490.00 Price as Selected")
puts getLowestNumberFromString("$9.90 or 5/$27.50 Price as Selected")
```

The regex breakdown:

- `(?<=(?<!\/)\$)` - assert that there is a `$` symbol not preceded with `/` right before...
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - optionally followed with a `.` followed by 1 or more digits

Note that if you only need to match floats with decimal part, remove the `?` and non-capturing group from the last subpattern (`/(?<=(?<!\/)\$)\d+\.\d+/` or even `/(?<=(?<!\/)\$)\d*\.?\d+/`).

Comment: I updated it now. I improved it when working on an alternative solution and forgot to update.

Comment: regex guru confirmed :)

Comment: @Jordan: So, [`min_by`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/min_by) receives a block (`&`) that is cast to float (`:to_f`)? Nice. Let's live and learn, thank you very much!

Comment: `&` is the [`to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) operator. Basically `&:foo` is equivalent to `proc {|obj| obj.foo }`, so `.min_by(&:to_f)` is equivalent to `.min_by {|value| value.to_f }`

Comment: I believe the above comment is off-topic.

Comment: @Jordan, a fine point `&` in `min_by(&:to_f)` actually does to things: it invokes ':to_proc' to convert the method `:to_f` to a proc (as you say), but  also, it then calls the proc.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing input can be relied upon to look like one of your three examples, how about this?

```
expr = /\$(\d+\.\d\d)\s+(?:or\s+\d+\/\$\d+\.\d\d\s+)?Price/

str = "$9.90 or 5/$27.50 Price as Selected"
str[expr, 1] # => "9.90"
```

Here it is on Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/CakoUt5Lo3

Explained:

```
expr = %r{
  \$          # literal dollar sign
  (\d+\.\d\d) # capture a price with two decimal places (assume no thousands separator)
  \s+         # whitespace
  (?:         # non-capturing group
    or\s+       # literal "or" followed by whitespace
    \d+\/       # one or more digits followed by literal "/"
    \$\d+\.\d\d # dollar sign and price
    \s+         # whitespace
  )?          # preceding group is optional
  Price       # the literal word "Price"
}x
```

You might use it like this:

```
MATCH_PRICE_EXPR = /\$(\d+\.\d\d)\s+(?:or\s+\d+\/\$\d+\.\d\d\s+)?Price/

def match_price(input)
  return unless input =~ MATCH_PRICE_EXPR
  $1.to_f
end

puts match_price("$13.90 Price as Shown")
# => 13.9

puts match_price("$590.50  $490.00 Price as Selected")
# => 490.0

puts match_price("$9.90 or 5/$27.50 Price as Selected")
# => 9.9
```

Comment: WOW! All solution just in single line *.*

Answer (score 0):

> My code works fine for all 3 types of strings. Just wondering how can
>   I improve that code

```
str = str.gsub(/ or \d\/[\$\d.]+/i, '')
str = /(\$[\d.]+) P/.match(str)
```

---

**Ruby Live Demo**

http://ideone.com/18XMjr

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you simply want the smallest dollar value in each line:

```
r = /
    \$    # match a dollar sign
    \d+   # match one or more digits
    \.    # match a decimal point
    \d{2} # match two digits
    /x    # extended mode

[str1, str2, str3].map { |s| s.scan(r).min_by { |s| s[1..-1].to_f } }
  #=> ["$13.90", "$490.00", "$9.90"]
```

Actually, you don't have to use a regex. You could do it like this:

```
def smallest(str)
  val = str.each_char.with_index(1).
        select { |c,_| c == ?$ }.
        map { |_,i| str[i..-1].to_f }.
        min
  "$%.2f" % val
end

smallest(str1) #=> "$13.90" 
smallest(str2) #=> "$490.00" 
smallest(str3) #=> "$9.90"
```

Answer (score 0):

A better regex is probably: `/\B\$(\d+\.\d{2})\b/`

```
str = "$590.50  $490.00 Price as Selected"
str.scan(/\B\$(\d+\.\d{2})\b/).flatten.min_by(&:to_f)
#=> "490.00"
```